# Add attachment (pdf) created within same sub to email

Tags: excel, vba

I need to modify this code to attach a PDF to an email. The name changes month over month and I am therefore unable to use a static reference.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub PrintToPDF()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim OlMail As Object
    Dim ToRecipient As Variant
    Dim CcRecipient As Variant
    Dim BccRecipient As Variant
    
'Specify the folder where the PDF files will be saved
    strPath = "C:\Users\..."
    
'Loop through each selected worksheet and print it as PDF
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        strFile = strPath & Format(Range("G9").Text, "YYYY-MM") & " XXXX0000 " & ws.Name & ".pdf"  
'Set the file name
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    Next ws

'Create email
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlMail = OlApp.createitem(olmailitem)

'Add recipients
    For Each ToRecipient In Array("user@domain.com")
        OlMail.Recipients.Add ToRecipient
    Next ToRecipient
    
    For Each CcRecipient In Array("user@domain.com", "user@domain.com", "user@domain.com")
        OlMail.Recipients.Add CcRecipient
    Next CcRecipient
    
    For Each BccRecipient In Array("user@domain.com")
        OlMail.Recipients.Add BccRecipient
    Next BccRecipient
    
'Fill in Subject field
    OlMail.Subject = "00-XXXX000 Billing"


'Add the pdf as an attachment
    OlMail.Attachments.Add **"dynamic filename stuff here"**
    OlMail.Display

    'OlMail.Send
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If you create the mail *before* exporting the PDF's, you can attach them in the `For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets` loop `OlMail.Attachments.Add strFile`   FYI possibly you want `strFile = strPath & Format(ws.Range("G9").Text` otherwise it always reads G9 from the active sheet.

Comment: If you want to add CC or BCC recipients you need to set the recipient `Type` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients#:~:text=changes%20the%20type%20of%20the%20Recipient%20object%20from%20the%20default%20(%22To%22)%20to%20CC.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am needing the information in range G9, as this contains the date I need included in the file name. Additionally, if I create the email before the export will the exports be saved? I do need these files for reference at a later date.

Comment: The files will remain wherever you save them to: attaching them to an email does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```vb
Sub PrintToPDF()
    
    Const PDF_PATH = "C:\Temp\" 'use Const for fixed values
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim OlApp As Object, OlMail As Object
    
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    OlMail.Subject = "00-XXXX000 Billing"
    
    'Populate the recipients
    AddRecipients OlMail, Array("user1@domain.com"), 1
    AddRecipients OlMail, _
       Array("user2@domain.com", "user3@domain.com", "user4@domain.com"), 2
    AddRecipients OlMail, Array("user5@domain.com"), 3
    'Export each selected sheet to PDF and add as attachments
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        strFile = PDF_PATH & Format(ws.Range("G9").Value, "YYYY-MM") & " XXXX0000 " & ws.Name & ".pdf"
        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
        OlMail.Attachments.Add strFile
    Next ws

    OlMail.Display
    'OlMail.Send
    
End Sub

'Add recipents from array `recips` to mail `objMail`
' `recipType` options: 1 = To, 2 = CC, 3 = BCC
Sub AddRecipients(objMail As Object, recips, recipType)
    Dim recip As Object, r
    For Each r In recips
        Set recip = objMail.Recipients.Add(r)
        recip.Type = recipType
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.